# Api MemoryStream c# , how this code works?

Tags: c#, stream, httprequest

I am here with a question, I know it is simple for you, but actually I need to understand what it does, line by line..

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var context = (System.Web.HttpContextBase)Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"];
    context.Request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    context.Request.InputStream.CopyTo(stream);
    strContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
    AppLog.Write("Request content length: " + strContent.Length);
}
```

Comment: This code assumes the incoming HTTP request has an Utf8-encoded body and copies it into a string. That answer isn't going to help you though. Read [ask] and explain what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: sorry for asking such things, I do not mean to waste your time..Thanks for your help codecaster

Comment: @CodeCaster and it does it badly; calling `stream.ToArray()` (unless you know that the length is manageable, and you're OK with the allocation) is not a good way to do that; likewise, there's no need to materialize a string to find the length - `Encoding`/`Encoder` has mechanisms to do that more efficiently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// create a MemoryStream to act as a buffer for some unspecified data
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    // obtain the http-context (not sure this is a good way to do it)
    var context = (System.Web.HttpContextBase)Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"];
    // reset the context's input stream to the start
    context.Request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    // copy the input stream to the buffer we allocated before
    context.Request.InputStream.CopyTo(stream);
    // create an array from the buffer, then use that array to
    // create  a string via the UTF8 encoding
    strContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
    // write the number of characters in the string to the log
    AppLog.Write("Request content length: " + strContent.Length);
}
```

Note that virtually everything here could be done much more efficiently. This is not good sample code.

Comment: thanks for taking time! I know it is a dummy question what I did, but thanks a lot!